# when I add record data, default value from sql server not added.. ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have trouble, I want to add record to database, and 1 row have default value from sql server, when I add record data, default value will null, how to I fix this

this for my Model

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[informasi] (
[id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[nama]     VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
[alamat]   VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
[belajar]  NVARCHAR (MAX) DEFAULT ('aktif') NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_informasi] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);
```

this for my add view

```
@model CRUD2.ViewModel.CostVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())

{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nama:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="nama" placeholder="Enter Name" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Alamat:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="alamat" placeholder="Enter Password" required/>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
        <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and this for my controler,

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetDataInDataBase(CostVM model)
    {

        informasi item = new informasi();
        item.nama = model.nama;
        item.alamat = model.alamat;

        db.informasis.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Register", new { id = item.id, id2 = item2.Id });

    }
```

I want if I add a record, fill form `nama` and `alamat`, after that row `belajar` in database will fill to with default values `aktif`.
this just a simple form, so I learn with 1 default values first..

Comment: if I add a value in controller maybe that will work, but I need to add without that, I want to add atuomatcili with default value in sql server, is that impossible? @AshleyMedway

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework doesn't read default values from SQL.

You need to either add the default value in your model, which may look something like this:

```
public class informasi
{
    public string belajar { get; set; } = "aktif";
}
```

Or as you mentioned in the comments you can do this in the controller.

```
informasi item = new informasi();
item.belajar = "aktif";
item.nama = model.nama;
item.alamat = model.alamat;

db.informasis.Add(item);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If I have 20 query use default value. is there a quick way to fill a query with the same value ? @AshleyMedway

Comment: @Kuujoe36 not really, when using entity framework you shouldn't really edit the database, you should make all changes in your model. So if you have default values all the values should be set in your model like in example 1.